# Removing the billing permision from a apk build in unity

Tags: unity, android, in-app-purchase

So recently we made a version of our game that is paid and not free. This of course means that we removed both ads and IAP capabilities. Now I'm sure that I have removed every single peice of code that references ads or IAP from scripts that get built into the apk but Unity still keeps adding the billing permision to the manifest. Apart from exporting a google android project and then modifying the manifest and then buidilng to apk what other options do I have to solve this ?

Comment: Have you tried looking in Unity's staging folder where the build is happening? Maybe the older manifest is cached there and it is being reused because it isn't detecting anything new to merge into a new manifest.

Answer (score 1):

At least in my case it turns out that under the services tab the IAP option was still ticked on. So even when no scripts reference it that are getting build I guess unity still adds the permision to the manifest.